# readObject() method not printing object

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, binaryfiles

In an assignment that I have to do, I have to write a Student object which comprises of a name, social security number, number of courses passed, and the grades for each of those courses. I made a gpa method to calculate the gpa based on and also made overrides of the writeObject and readObject methods with my own methods. 
[Here](http://pastebin.com/dNMrc1zK) is the complete source code- http://pastebin.com/dNMrc1zK

This is what it looks like without the getter and setter methods for each instance:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Student implements Serializable{
        private String name;
        private int ssNum;
        private int coursesCompleted;
        private char[] grades;

        public Student(String n, int num, int c){
                n = name;
                num = ssNum;
                c = coursesCompleted;
        }

        public String getName() {
                return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
        }

        public int getSsNum() {
                return ssNum;
        }

        public void setSsNum(int ssNum) {
                this.ssNum = ssNum;
        }

        public int getCoursesCompleted() {
                return coursesCompleted;
        }

        public void setCoursesCompleted(int coursesCompleted) {
                this.coursesCompleted = coursesCompleted;
        }

        public char[] getGrades() {
                return grades;
        }

        public void setGrades(char[] grades) {
                this.grades = grades;
        }
        public double gpa(char[] grades){

                double gpa = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
                        if (grades[i] == 'A'){
                                gpa += 4.0;
                        }
                        else if (grades[i] == 'B'){
                                gpa += 3.0;
                        }
                        else if (grades[i] == 'C'){
                                gpa += 2.0;
                        }
                        else if (grades[i] == 'D'){
                                gpa += 1.0;
                        }
                        else if (grades[i] == 'F'){
                                gpa += 0.0;
                        }
                }

                return gpa / grades.length;

        }

        public void ReadObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException{
                String readTitle = "";

                for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++){
                        readTitle += in.readChar();
                }
                ssNum = in.readInt();
                coursesCompleted = in.readInt();

                for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
                        grades[i] = in.readChar();
                }
        }
        public void WriteObjectOverride(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

                out.writeChars(name);
                out.writeInt(ssNum);
                out.writeInt(coursesCompleted);

                for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
                        out.writeChar(grades[i]);
                }
                gpa(grades);
        }
        public String toString(){
                   String student = name + " " +  "\nGPA: " + gpa(grades);
                   return student;
                }
}


public void ReadObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException{
    String readTitle = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++){
        readTitle += in.readChar();
    }
    ssNum = in.readInt();
    coursesCompleted = in.readInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
        grades[i] = in.readChar();
    }
}
public void WriteObjectOverride(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

    out.writeChars(name);
    out.writeInt(ssNum);
    out.writeInt(coursesCompleted);

    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
        out.writeChar(grades[i]);
    }
    gpa(grades);
}
public String toString(){
       String student = name + " " +  "\nGPA: " + gpa(grades);
       return student;
    }
}
```

I then have to write a separate program which writes the object to a file. I made a constructor so that it gives the name, ss number, and courses completed a value and then I used a setter method to set the grades array value. I then used the values I had to use writeObject and wrote the object like this:

```
            Student john = new Student("John Doe", 123456, 4);
    Student jane = new Student("Jane Doe", 987654, 3);
    Student jack = new Student("Jack Doe", 528491, 4);

    ObjectOutputStream out;

    john.setGrades(student1);
    jane.setGrades(student2);
    jack.setGrades(student3);

    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("students.bin")));

        out.writeObject(john);
        out.writeObject(jane);
        out.writeObject(jack);

        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The problem I'm having is that when I use another program to execute the readObject() method, like this:

```
    public static void main (String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    Student student = null;
    try(ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("students.bin"));){

        student = (Student)in.readObject();
        System.out.println(student);
    }
```

It prints a line which not something I expected:

```
UnitSeven.Student@70dea4e
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem so that it shows the actual object? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: As a side note: your gpa method could be refactored to add the numbers to gpa as you go and divide by grades.length, thereby eliminating the need for a second array.

Comment: It also looks like your read and write object overrides are going to need some work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your overrides having the wrong names as Kumar Abhinav pointed out, you have several issues.

Your `readObject` is using `names.length` and `grades.length` but neither has been initialized. You will probably need to modifiy `writeObject` to output the length of the name and then read that length before reading the name or just write and read the name as a String object. You can use `coursesCompleted` to determine how many grades to read. You also don't do anything with the `readTitle` variable.

Your `writeObject` method calls the `gpa` method but does not use the return value.

Comment: There is no need to call gpa from writeObject and you should put back the loop that writes the grade letters

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is completely wrong. You are using `ReadObject` with capital `R`, use `readObject` and you have not implemented `writeObject`. These two private methods must have an exact signature as defined as they are call-back methods. The way your code currently works, it's calling the default way of serializing/deserializing Objects.

1. The method signature of your `ReadObject` method is not matching the one required.

   ```
   public void ReadObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException { ... }
   ```

   should be

   ```
   private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException { ... }
   ```
2. The same applies for your attempt at the `writeObject` method.

   ```
   public void WriteObjectOverride(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
   ```

   should be

   ```
   private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException { ... }
   ```

Also note: All [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) Objects and primitives are themselves serializble, so you may as well change the logic of writing data to your stream

To prevent your method from printing out a hashcode next to the class name,  implement your own `toString()` method in the `Student` class. Please consult [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29140402/4464702) question for more details:

> To print something different when you call
>   System.out.println(myObject), you must override the toString() method
>   in your own class. Here's a simple example:
>
> ```
> public class Person {
>
>     private String name;
>
>     // constructors and other methods omitted
>
>     @Override   public String toString() {
>      return name;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Now if we print a Person, we see their name rather than `com.foo.Person@12345678`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But I'm encountering another problem. It seems that the object keeps returning null. I can't figure out why it's doing that. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @Foxwood211 Could you post the results ,object which is returning null because UnitSeven.Student@70dea4e would not have been returned in the first place

Comment: These are the results:
`null 
GPA: 3.25`
The GPA method and the array seems to have a value but for some reason the object itself is null.

Comment: Can you please post the entire code for Class you are serializing

Comment: Code was too long to post in the comments, but here's a link to the class. http://pastebin.com/dNMrc1zK

Comment: The code yo uare using is compltely wrong.You are using ReadObject with capital R ,use readObject and you have not implemented writeObject... These two private methods must have exact signature as defined as they are call back methods.Your program is calling default readObject and default writeObject

Comment: @Foxwood211 Check my answer now

Comment: @KumarAbhinav did you really mean that ReadObject should be writeObject and vice versa?

Comment: @JimRhodes Typo error.Let me correct it.Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @KumarAbhinav Is it ok if my writeObject looks like this? http://pastebin.com/hfKaruZm

Answer (score 0):

When you execute:

```
System.out.println(student);
```

what actually happens is that student object's `toString()` method is called. Since you did not override `toString()` method for student's class what you run is Object class's, which is the parent of all classes in java, `toString()` method. This Object class's toString() returns the student's class name and a hashcode. Hashcode is the mumbo jumbo number that you are seeing. This hashcode is the standard identifier in java.

What you should do is override Object class's `toString()` method in your `Student` class in order to print your desired output.

Comment: He defines a `toString()` method in `Student`: `public String toString() { return name + " \nGPA:" + gpa(grades); }` (I simplified it a bit)